# get dominant color of an image node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, amazon-s3, colors

I'm trying to get the dominant color of an image I have on my computer.
I installed `imagemagick` and `dominant-color` before using this code.
I get the result of `undefined` and `000000`.

Why is that happening? What did I do wrong?

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
fs = require('fs');
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

const resizeImg = require('resize-img');
var color = require('dominant-color'),
    imgPath = './Users/ADIBAR/Desktop/cloud/beach_life-normal.jpg';

color(imgPath,function(err,color){
    console.log(color);
})

color(imgPath,{format:'rgb'},function(err,color){
    console.log(color);
})

// For dev purposes only
AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: '', secretAccessKey: '' });

var fileStream = fs.createReadStream('beach_life-normal.jpg');
fileStream.on('error', function (err) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
});  

fileStream.on('open', function () {
  var s3 = new AWS.S3();




resizeImg(fs.readFileSync('beach_life-normal.jpg'), {width: 128, height:128}).then(buf => {
    fs.writeFileSync('beach_life-normal-new.jpg', buf);
    //upload//
    s3.putObject({
      Bucket: 'adinoauploadefile',
      Key: 'beach_life-normal-new.jpg',
      Body: 'beach_life-normal-new.jpg'
    }, function (err) {
     if (err) { throw err; }
    });
  });  
});
```

Comment: Do you get any errors from the `color` callbacks?

Comment: `console.log(err)` gives you `undefined`? Or is that the result of `console.log(color)`?

Comment: the console.log(color)

Comment: Ok, what do you get if you add in the `console.log(err)` line just before the `console.log(color)`?

Comment: it writes error: command failed: invalid parameter -/Users

and it writes to console.log =>null

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is with the image path - either use an absolute path:

```
imgPath = 'C:/[path to your file]/Users/ADIBAR/Desktop/cloud/beach_life-normal.jpg';
```

or a relative one (put the image in the same folder as your script):

```
imgPath = './beach_life-normal.jpg
```

Comment: I tried changing the imgPath before (the image is in the same folder as my app.js) and it still did the same error.